# how store many data like comments in database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

i have a catalog shopping system that has 9 major categories 
it has over billion comments in each specific category
now i want redesign the site for optimizing performance
how could i store comments that has best performance when retrieving comments?
the comments are growing very fast, what about one year later that comments get bigger?
i think about separate comments for each specific category like comment_1, comment_2 and so on
what is the best design for storing comments?
and one question, how many rows does affect performance?

Comment: Good indexing affects performance, not purely the volume of data

Comment: You are designing application code to store over a billion rows.  This is a topic that would make a full-year research project.  You need an expert in database architecture, and asking questions on SO will not give you the expertise you need.  For the sake of your client, please find a qualified expert to help you.

Comment: @Jim Garrison.its just an ordinary comment system that i want design database for,not very complicated i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Normalise your data.
2. Add appropriate indexes.
3. Make effective use of application caching to avoid having to reread comments.
4. Describe any specific problems that you then encounter.

Comment: thanks,i was thinking instead of having one big table for all comments, it is better to split them into 8-9 tables like comment_1 and ...what's your opinion?

Comment: It's unlikely to be beneficial. The most likely access paths for the comments are to access by their parent record (product?) and maybe "helpfulness score" or date, or by user and date. Index the access paths you need. Breaking out the table into multiple tables might be of help if you expected to need to regularly scan nearly every comment for a single category -- it would be similar to table partitioning in that respect -- but that seems unlikely.